# php cicle while issue when $x is multiple of 4 or more

Tags: php, html, while-loop

I must close my div after some cicle while request

The problem is I must close the div only every multiple 4, and i have resolve like this

```
   if   ($x % 4 ==  0)  {   
    ?></ul>
</div>
    <?php
    }
```

But the problem arrive if my posts not are multiple of 4
for example 10 posts
the div will close after 4--> after 8  but not after 10

How can i close a div every multiple 4 and when cicle is finish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the `ul` and `div` tags outside of your loop.

This way, as soon as your loop finishes it automatically closes the tags.

You may want to check how many iterations were made, if it is a multiple of 4 don't close it again, or your html structure might break.

Comment: omg....it's true...i have spend 2 days only for this...thx very much...

Comment: @FrankFrank You're welcome, if this fixed the problem ,don't forget to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$x - 1` to replace you `$x`, and add another `</div>` out of the whild loop at the end.

Answer (score 0):

after the end of your main loop use this code to ensure that tags will be ended, not that you have to use this if statement after you end your main loop because for example if you don't use it and $x=12 then it will be two end of tag

```
if($x % 4 !=  0){
?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php 
}
?>
```